# Splitting & joining streams in apache flink

Tags: scala, stream, apache-flink

I think I have a rather non-standard usecase. I want to split my source-stream into several streams using the `filter` function:

```
val dataStream:DataStream[MyEvent] = ...
val s1 = dataStream.filter(...).map(...)
val s2 = dataStream.filter(...).map(...)
```

I also have a timestamp extractor (the incoming events will have a timestamp attached to them in XML):

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
...

dataStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyTimestampExtractor)
...

class MyTimestampExtractor extends AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[Elem]
{
  override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement:Elem, extractedTimestamp:Long):Watermark = new Watermark(extractedTimestamp)
  override def extractTimestamp(element:Elem, previousElementTimestamp:Long):Long = XmlOperations.getDateTime(element, "@timestamp").getMillis
}
```

I chose this approach since and not simply do a single stream (`val s = dataStream.filter(...).map(...).filter(...).map(...)`) because I want to build a *network* which splits/combines arbitrary streams (e.g. s1+s2->c1, s1+s3->c2, c2+s4->c3, ...)

Now when sending events through the above example, it might be that event E1 ends up in both s1 and s2. This means, in my understanding, that the very same event E1 is put as first instance into s1 (E1a) and also put as second instance into s2 (E1b).

So what I want to do now is to re-unite E1a and E1b into a combined E1 which resembles the E1 which as both the transformations of s1 and s2.

I tried:

```
val c1 = s1.join(s2)
  .where(_.key).equalTo(_.key)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
  .apply((e1a, e2b) => { printf("Got e1a and e1b"); e1a })
```

However it seems like the events never reach the apply function, and I can't find out why.

What is wrong in my example? Will my approach / idea of a network of streams like this work at all?

Comment: Take a look at `union` rather than `join`.

Comment: Can you elaborate this some more? How can I achieve the same functionality with the `union` function?

Comment: Nevermind; I hadn't read your question carefully enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you arranged for there to be watermarks? When working with event time, a window will only be triggered when a watermark arrives that advances the event time clock past the end of the window. You do this with a timestamp extractor / watermark generator; see [an example from the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness) for more details.

If one of the streams is sometimes idle that can also cause problems, as the lack of watermarks on the idle stream will hold back watermarks for any streams it is connected to.

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may find it easier to use a CoProcessFunction than a time-windowed join. Take a look at the exercises on [stateful enrichment](https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-flatmap.html) and [expiring state](https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-processfunction.html) from the Flink training site for examples.

Comment: I edited my post to describe the timestamp functions. In my testing, I only used 1 single event, which is going into `dataStream`, and later into both `s1` and `s2`. So there is only 2 event instances in `s1` and `s2` which have the same timestamp.
I will try the stateful enrichment variant, and see how it goes. One question, however. When trying to build a **network of streams**, I might end up with multiple *joins* (implemented via connect/CoProcessFunction) which handle the same event. This might not work with the stored state, because the key/event is the same for multiple joins?

Comment: If you only have one event, then that explains why the window never fires. With event-time windows, there has to be a watermark with a timestamp after the window, to trigger the window. To generate such a watermark will require a second event. Also, your timestamp extractor assumes that the events are in order, by timestamp. If this is true you should just use an AscendingTimestampExtractor.

Comment: Multiple joins (per key) can work, but each join will have to manage its own state -- there's no way to share state between the joins.

Comment: Okay that is fine. Actually I tested this technique and it perfectly works. When E1 enters the pipeline, it is assigned a UUID, which I later use to key all streams, and to match the event-instances again in the `RichCoFlatMapFunction`. 
As I am planning to build a potentially big network of streams which are forked/joined using the `filter`- and `connect`- functions, do you think this approach will be an issue when the number of streams gets big?
I am looking for the best/correct approach to best exploit flink's abilities to scale in a cluster environment.

Comment: You should consider using side outputs for the forking -- that might yield a cleaner and more performant solution than filters (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/side_output.html). But otherwise this should be fine -- this overall approach is reasonably common.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. Thanks for your help.